# How do I add an additional column to this dataframe to convert coordinates to Zip Code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying to add an additional column to my dataframe as it already has coordinates, but I need the zip code.

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

url3 = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chrisc617/Data-Bootcamp'
url4 = '-Final-Project/master/NYC_Transit_Subway_Entrance_And_Exit_Data.csv'
url5 = url3+url4
trains = pd.read_csv(url5)
trains.columns

trains['Zip Code'] = (location = geolocator.reverse(trains['Station Location'])
print(location.address[-18:-13]))
```

Is the above code not the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
trains['Zip Code'] = trains['Station Location'].apply(lambda x: geolocator.reverse(x))
```